# Как реализовать алгоритм на Python3?

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Использовать автоматическое форматирование запрещено.

[мои продвижения](http://cs624727.vk.me/v624727250/3145/kRvHZJdyq5g.jpg)

Задача: **вводятся числа, через пробел, надо вывести их в порядке возрастания в кортеже**, чисел не более 1000, и сами числа лежат в диапазоне от 10^-9 до 10^9.
**Пример**: вводят 10 5 20, выводится (5, 10, 20).

Мой алгоритм:

1. Через стрип преобразовываем то, что ввели в вид [a1, a2, ..., an]
2. Далее делаем функцию, которая находит в каком-то списке наименьший элемент, запихивает его в пустой кортеж и затем этот элемент удаляет из списка.
3. Теперь создаем цикл while с условием, пока список не опустеет, выполняем функцию от списка.
4. Выводим кортеж.

Прошу помочь мне реализовать это на Python3, у меня не получается. **Реализовать именно это**.

Comment: Согласно правилам форума: Не стоит задавать вопросы с просьбой выполнить бесплатно или за деньги какую-либо работу, связанную с программированием: форум не является фриланс-биржей.


Покажите чего ты достиг в решении той или иной проблемы.

Comment: Прикрепил, к шапке.

Comment: Пожалуйста, используй более информативный заголовок, например: "Как вывести входные числа, разделённые пробелом, в порядке возрастания в кортеже на Python 3?"

Answer (score 1):

Так?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

inputString = "123 234 5645 6575 234 1024"

stringToList = inputString.split()
stringToList.sort(key=int)

listToTuple = ()
for x in stringToList:
    listToTuple += (x,)

print (listToTuple); //output ('123', '234', '234', '1024', '5645', '6575')
```

Comment: Самая первая строка - использовать автоматическое форматирование запрещено.

Comment: @Hashirama, поправьте меня, если я не прав. Под автоматическим форматированием имеется ввиду вывод через print? То есть вам надо вручную собрать строку вида ('123', '234', '234', '1024', '5645', '6575')? Или имеется ввиду автоматическая сортировка, а не форматирование?

Comment: Вот точнее:
В этой задаче запрещено использовать встроенное форматирование tuple - его необходимо воспроизвести самостоятельно.

Comment: Ну тут тогда простор для размышлений, поправил ответ на один из возможных вариантов. В отличие от вашего алгоритма изменен самостоятельный поиск минимального элемента на встроенный sort() и вместо while с удалением, простой for-in проход по уже отсортированному списку.

Comment: Все, разобрался, надо int(x) в кортеже написать. Спасибо еще раз

Comment: Можно просто вызвать `tuple()`, чтобы преобразовать список в кортеж: `some_tuple = tuple(some_list)`

Comment: @jfs, выше сказали, что tuple() использовать запрещено.

Comment: @Alex Krass: насколько я понимаю, нельзя использовать `str(some_tuple)`, а не сам конструктор. `x,` также создаёт tuple.

Comment: @jfs, вариант подобран исключительно по аналогии с описанием в посте и пояснением тут в комментариях автором не использовать только сам конструктор tuple(). По правкам поста можете увидеть, мой первый вариант как раз был с tuple(some_list). 

--------
А вот нужно ли было сделать так или вывести строку, по виду похожую на вывод кортежа, как в вашем ответе, это мне не известно. Гадать и додумывать что-то свое не буду)) Пусть два варианта висят, кому-то да пригодятся, может быть.

--------
Может быть и так, как вы говорите. В общем предлагаю оставить это на усмотрение отвечающего, место кончилос

Comment: В посте и комментарии сказано: *"автоматическое форматирование запрещено"*, *"запрещено использовать встроенное форматирование tuple"*. Я это понимаю, что нельзя использовать: `print(listToTuple)` (берёт tuple и форматирует его для вывода). А `listToTuple = tuple(stringToList)` можно, потому что нет никакого форматирования, просто создаёт кортеж из списка (никаких промежуточных строк).

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вывести входные числа, разделённые пробелом, в порядке возрастания в кортеже на Python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
numbers = input("Введи числа, разделённые пробелом:").split()
# воспроизводим самостоятельно `print(tuple(sorted(map(int, numbers))))`
print("(", end='') # начинаем кортеж (tuple)
# печатаем в возрастающем порядке через запятую
print(", ".join(sorted(numbers, key=int)), end='')
print(")") # заканчиваем кортеж (tuple)
```